# Today Extension AutoLayout Not Working

Tags: swift, autolayout, today-extension

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to get my entire extension to display. It should show four rows but it always cuts off like this:

[image: Cut off Today extension]

I read some threads and tried preferredContentSize but it doesn't work either:

```
func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 400)        
    completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
}
```

What's frustrating it that I shouldn't even need preferredContentSize because I set the auto layout constraints!

[image: autolayout constraints]

You'll notice the bottom constraint is a dotted line because it's currently set to a 999 priority but I've tried it at 1000 too.

How do I fix this? Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you are talking about, I have the same problem.

I seams that your widget cannot be higher than a certain height for your device. But you can enable an expanded mode, where you can toggle between a compact and expanded view of your widget.

I guess it should clean up the today view from too large widgets.

This article will help you: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48930

The important pieces are:

```
self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded

func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if (activeDisplayMode == .compact) {
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize;
    }
    else {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 359, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It does force me into using "Show More" / "Show Less" but I can make that work.

Comment: Same for me, I also have to use more/less know, but why not - makes sense somehow :)

Comment: Does this really solve the problems? This creates the static height 200, wouldnt you want that to be adjust automatically with auto-layout? I got a question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524154/dynamic-height-using-auto-layout-in-today-extension