# Dynamic height using Auto Layout in Today Extension

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, today-extension

**EDIT:** My "original" problem has been solved, it was restricted to 110 height, by `"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000000985b0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fc83af0aeb0.height == 110   (active)>"`, but that was before I read about `NCWidgetDisplayMode`, `.Compact` and `.Expanded`, which apparently was introduced in iOS 10.

**Funny thing:** Looks like they had the bug when they presented the new feature in iOS 10 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/101/?time=3221)

With that implemented though, I still don't get the correct height adjustment. See relevant code details below, and for the full source code check out: https://github.com/everlof/TodayExtensionSample.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    lbl.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae tempor nulla, in volutpat lectus. Sed quis orci sit amet velit cursus congue non accumsan turpis. Phasellus quis augue lobortis, pharetra arcu vitae, condimentum nunc. Nam rutrum massa ac feugiat eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec non erat orci. Ut consequat faucibus sapien, et luctus magna posuere tempor."
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    lbl.backgroundColor = .blue
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

and `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange` (which returns zero height so that it is using Auto Layout instead):

```
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if activeDisplayMode == .expanded {
        print("EXPANDED")
        preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        setupLabel()
    } else if activeDisplayMode == .compact {
        print("COMPACT")
        preferredContentSize = maxSize
        setupLabel()
    }
}
```

and `setupLabel` (which removes it and adds it):

```
func setupLabel() {
    lbl.removeFromSuperview()
    view.addSubview(lbl)
    lbl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
    lbl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -18).isActive = true
    lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
    lbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -18).isActive = true
    lbl.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, for: .vertical)
}
```

If the extension is `STARTED` in `.expanded` it looks correct:

[image]

if 'Show less' is pressed it looks correct:

[image]

however, if 'Show more' is pressed, then it wont expand again:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you press **"Show More"**, `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange` method is called with `activeDisplayMode` as `expanded`.

According to your code, in expanded mode you are setting the `preferredContentSize` as:

```
preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
```

So, it takes the minimum height allowed for widget, i.e. 110.

Try this:

```
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize)
{
    if activeDisplayMode == .expanded
    {
        let size = self.sampleLabel.systemLayoutSizeFitting(self.sampleLabel.bounds.size)
        preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: size.height)
    }
    else
    {
        preferredContentSize = maxSize
    }
}
```